# How does a trusting Active Directory domain controller validate credentials that exist only in the trusted domain?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldapjs

Suppose an Active Directory domain controller `smallapp.local` which trusts another domain `bigenterprise.local`.

There is a user Alice in the `bigenterprise.local` and she is able to login into `smallapp.local` with her password using LDAP bind. As `smallapp.local` does not have the hash of her password, I assume it must be somehow forwarded to her "home" domain `bigenterprise.local`.

How does that happen?

For more background, I'm using node library `ldapjs` on a Windows server like this and the authentication succeeds just fine, but I don't understand how Windows validates that password belonging to another domain.

```
const ldap = require('ldapjs');
const client = ldap.createClient({ url: 'ldap://localhost' });
const disti = 'CN=Alice,CN=Users,DC=XXX,DC=YYY';
const password = 'mypass';

client.bind(disti, password, (err) => { /* do things */ })
```